# Combobox ItemSource issue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have the following code

```
<ComboBox x:Name="hotelComboBox"
          ItemsSource="{Binding HotelCollection}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding ActiveHotel,Mode=TwoWay}"
          Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          Visibility="{Binding IsFirstTimeUser, ConverterParameter=Inverse, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    <TextBlock Text="Select Something"
               IsHitTestVisible="False">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                        Value="Hidden" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=hotelComboBox,Path=SelectedItem}"
                                 Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style></TextBlock>
</ComboBox>
```

When i added the TextBlock insode the combo box, i am getting an error like "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource."

If I remove the item Source binding, i am not getting this error.but i need to use this Item Source. any options?

Thanks

Comment: If you cannot post whole code (due to it's length), at least post the valid one. In your markup I don't see closing tag for combobox so it is difficult to  know If that TextBox is inside it or outside?

Comment: Do set the `ComboBox.Items` property in code?

Comment: @Empereur Aiman still the same error,but still i need binding there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `ItemsSource` and at the same time defining your custom items in XAML.

I guess, the thing you are looking for is `ItemTemplate` property of `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the Items is the content property of any [ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) (such as ComboBox). Thus when you put any element inside ComboBox it automatically adds to the Items collection. In your case you need to do one of the following things:

- Declare TextBlock near ComboBox
- Use the [ItemTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) property
- Stop using ItemsSource and use the Items instead